# Suppose that $g$ is an integer satisfying $g\not\equiv \pm 1 \mod p \text{ and } g^q \not\equiv 1 \mod p$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime such that $q=\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$ is also prime. Suppose that $g$ is an integer satisfying $$g\not\equiv \pm 1 \mod p \text{ and } g^q \not\equiv 1 \mod p$$ Prove that $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Well $q=\frac{1}{2}(p-1) \iff 2q=p-1=\phi(p)$. So $g^{2q}=g^{\phi(p)} \mod p$.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $g^{2q} \equiv g^{\phi(p)}\equiv 1\mod{p}$. Since $q$ is prime, the order of $g$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\times$ is either $1$, $2$, $q$, or $2q$. The first three of these are ruled out by the given conditions, so that $g$ generates $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\times$ and therefore is a primitive root modulo $p$.